# How to find all Wikipedia pages related to a named entity?

Tags: nlp, mediawiki, stanford-nlp, wikipedia, named-entity-recognition

Given a text, I am looking to find links to all Wikipedia pages related to named entities mentioned in the text. Is there a reliable way to do this?

For example, consider the text,

> Mark Elliot Zuckerberg is an American internet entrepreneur and
>   philanthropist.

" Given this, I am looking at output with the following links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zuckerberg
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrepreneurship
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philanthropy

Is this possible at all given the current state of NLP? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is called [Entity Linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking). There are many academic papers discussing solutions to this problem, but only few of them provide an implementation.

[OpenTapioka](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09131) from Oxford has an [open source implementation](https://github.com/wetneb/opentapioca) and an [online demo](https://opentapioca.org).

[SWAT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.03580.pdf) from the University of Pisa has a  [publically available API](https://sobigdata.d4science.org/web/tagme/swat-api).

Comment: Super helpful! At the outset, Univ. of Pisa seems to do a relatively better job at entity linking.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jindřich told you, you should undoubtly have a look at entity linking, sometimes also (named) entity disambiguation or "wikification". A lot has been done on this subject in academics (have a look a TAC, KBP, NEEL challenges).

Many software do this, just to name a few:

- [DBpedia Spotlight](https://www.dbpedia-spotlight.org/demo/)
- [IBM Watson](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2016/10/entity-linking/)
- [Babelfy](http://babelfy.org)

Be aware that results are highly dependent on the kind of text you'll process, and that you'll probably need to evaluate the reliability of software before using them.